# How to hide minimize and maximize in uwp project but to keep close botton?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need some help in hiding minimize and maximize buttons in the `Titlebar` but keep close button just like the following screenshot. Is there any api could do this?

Thanks in advance :).
[image: title bar]

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot looks  your app run in the [**Tablet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/continuum) model . You could enable the app to run in the Tablet model. But current, there is no api to enable **Tablet** model programming. So, you could check **Tablet model** option in **Action Center** manually.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, how that answer is related to the question. What am I missing?

Comment: @IInspectable, I think the answer has described clearly, if you have some questions please feel free post in the comment.